# need to remove last polyline and create current polyline

Tags: android, google-maps, directions, google-polyline

i do google map with google direction i use class http://www.akexorcist.com/2015/12/google-direction-library-for-android-en.html
that someone build for google direction. everything is work good, 
and the polyline show on the map. but when i need to click another direction like walking direction or drive direction i see 2 polyline on the map and i want to see only the current polyline.

here i create the polyline
and remove the polyline in the start, then the polyline not show at all.
i dont want that. i want when i click else button the polyline will remove.
i try to put, polyline.remove(); on button click else but the problem that if, polyline.remove(); outside the parentheses, polyline.remove(); dont remove the polyline. i need to call polyline.remove(); when i click other button but i stuck.
here is the code:

```
    switch (direction.getStatus()) {
        case RequestResult.OK:
            Route route = direction.getRouteList().get(0);

            Leg leg = route.getLegList().get(0);

            ArrayList<LatLng> pointList = leg.getDirectionPoint();

            List<Step> stepList = direction.getRouteList().get(0).getLegList().get(0).getStepList();
            ArrayList<PolylineOptions> polylineOptionList = DirectionConverter.createTransitPolyline(this, stepList, 5, Color.RED, 3, Color.BLUE);
            for (PolylineOptions polylineOption : polylineOptionList) {
                polyline = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOption);
                polyline.remove();

            }

                break;
```

2.when i click in walking button i want the transit polyline will remove
that we have just all the time, only one polyline in the map.
how i do that?

```
   bWalking.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            if (locationGpsLatLng == null) {
                                                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Need GPS location", `enter code here`Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();{
                                                    return;
                                                }
                                            }
                                            if (markerLocation == null) {
                                                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Type on marker bathroom for destination", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            } else {
                                            sendRequestWalkingDirection();


                                        }
                                    };
                                    private void sendRequestWalkingDirection() {
                                        GoogleDirection.withServerKey(APIKEY)
                                                .from(locationGpsLatLng)
                                                .to(markerLocation)
                                                .transportMode(TransportMode.WALKING)
                                                .execute(new DirectionCallback() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onDirectionSuccess(Direction direction, String rawBody) {
                                                        Log.d("onDirectionSuccess", "status: " + direction.getStatus());
                                                        requestOk(direction, rawBody);
                                                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(locationGpsLatLng).draggable(false).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                                                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
                                                        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(locationGpsLatLng, 15);
                                                        mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                                                    }
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onDirectionFailure(Throwable t) {
                                                        return;
                                                    }
                                                });
                                    }
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `mMap.clear();` after the button click.
That method will remove all the polylines.

[GoogleMap class documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#public-methods)

**UPDATE**

You need to save the polylines to some list and then remove them when the button is clicked

```
private List<Polyline> polylines;
```

Add the polylines to the list

```
polylines = new ArrayList<>();
for (PolylineOptions polylineOption : polylineOptionList) {
    polyline = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOption);
    polylines.add(polyline);
}
```

After button click

```
for (Polyline polyline : polylines) {
    polyline.remove();
}
```

Comment: mMap.clear(); clear all the map include all my markers its not good for me

Comment: read here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

the better answer to this is you call following function on clear or whatever button/View click :

```
public onClick(View v){
if(googleMap!=null && polygon!=null && polyline!=null && polylineOptions!=null && 
                polygonOptions!=null){
            polylineOptions.getPoints().clear();
            polygonOptions.getPoints().clear();
            googleMap.clear();
            polyline.remove();
            polygon.remove();
        }
}
```